# On Android 14 Samsung exit transition on activity is wobbling

Tags: android

On Android 14 Samsung exit transition on activity is wobbling. How to avoid such behavior when back pressed.

Custom animation for activity is not working.

Enter transition is working fine but when clear click on back button the screen is shaking and wobbling animation